# Error while running the node js application because of typescript file

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

These are the errors that are coming :

> ```
> D:\agent-master>npm run build
>
> > agent@0.1.0 build D:\agent-master
> > tsc
>
> node_modules/@types/whatwg-fetch/index.d.ts(6,1): error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'whatwg-streams'.
> node_modules/@types/whatwg-fetch/index.d.ts(97,11): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStream'.
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 2
> npm ERR! agent@0.1.0 build: `tsc`
> npm ERR! Exit status 2
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the agent@0.1.0 build script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\tushar.gupta\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-12-12T13_36_11_813Z-debug.log
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may be missing the package `@types/node` which contains all of the typings, including `ReadableStream`, that are node specific. Try installing that and see if it fixes your problem